# In Postgres i am trying to return the value but it shows a error

Tags: postgresql-9.1

In postgres I am trying to return this but it shows a error

```
select substr('10111',3,1) as aa_code
return aa_code;


ERROR:  syntax error at or near "return"
LINE 2:  return aa_code;
         ^
********** Error **********
```

Comment: Please show us the complete source of your stored function (`return` is only valid in a PL/pgSQL function).

Answer (score 0):

Why use the return at all?

```
=# select substr('10111',3,1) as aa_code;
 aa_code
---------
 1
(1 row)
```